# How to make a public variable from a "public ref class" in c++?

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, public, ref

How do you allow a variable to be at public/global scope of a "public ref class"?

Visual C++ [2010]

In my main DLL main.h:

```
namespace fdll {

 public ref class foo
 {
   public:
     int bar(int num);
  };

}
```

In my DLL main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"
int fdll::foo::bar(int num)
{
  return num;
}
```

In another project:

```
#using <main.dll>
#include "main.h"
fdll::foo f; <--- error wtf
int main()
{
  Console::WriteLine(fdll.bar(2));
  return 0;
}
```

Error given:

error C3145: 'f' : global or static variable may not have managed type 'fdll::foo'

may not declare a global or static variable, or a member of a native type that refers to objects in the gc heap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables are not supported for CLR objects, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3145).

Create a global class and use static to imitate global variable or only declare CLR variables in function scope.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Even though that link is helpfull, I decided to change my CLR/DLL to a Static Library project to help solve my problems. This isn't my real code though, I gave a broad example for help.